# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jakarta-mail

I want to send a email from my gmail account to the another mail account using eclipse.I used apache tomcat 7.0.34 as my web server and use port 8080 for apache server(HTTP/1.1) and use JRE 7 as system library and also include mail.jar and activation.jar in Libraries under Java Resources.

In the below my jsp page is given,where the recipient address is entered and submit to the server.

**SendMail.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="ControllerMail">
            Recipient Address : <input type="email" name="to" ><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="pageType" value="sendmail"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, My servlet class is given below.

**ControllerMail.java**

```
package com.sendmail.controller;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ControllerMail extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ControllerMail() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doProcess(request,response);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doProcess(request,response);
    }

    protected void doProcess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String pageType = request.getParameter("pageType");
        if(pageType.equals("SendMail"))
        {
            String to = request.getParameter("to");

            //Get the session object
              Properties props = new Properties();
              props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
              props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
              props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
              props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
              props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

              Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
               new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
               protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               return new PasswordAuthentication("********@gmail.com","********");//change accordingly
               }
              });

            //compose message
              try {
               MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
               message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("********@gmail.com"));//change accordingly
               message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
               message.setSubject("Greetings");
               message.setContent("Hi,what's up","text/html");

               //send message
               Transport.send(message);

               System.out.println("message sent successfully");

              } catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}
        }
    }

}
```

But when I run my project on server that mean when I right click on my SendMail.jsp page and click on "run on server",the following errors are occured.

```
Mar 17, 2015 7:41:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin;F:\Software\JavaMailAPI\activation-jaf1.1.1.jar;F:\Software\JavaMailAPI\java-mail-1.4.4.jar;F:\Software\eclipse-jee-luna-SR1a-win32\eclipse;;.
Mar 17, 2015 7:41:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SendEmail' did not find a matching property.
Mar 17, 2015 7:41:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Mar 17, 2015 7:41:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 17, 2015 7:41:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 539 ms
Mar 17, 2015 7:41:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 17, 2015 7:41:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Mar 17, 2015 7:41:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SendEmail]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SendEmail]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 20 more

Mar 17, 2015 7:41:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Mar 17, 2015 7:41:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Mar 17, 2015 7:41:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 249 ms
```

After 45 seconds,there will show a dialog box and it displays "Starting Tomcatv7.0 Server at localhost" encountered a problem.

Comment: Does your application compile in eclipse?  If so you should add the same jars on your project build path to your `web-inf/lib` folder

Comment: After insert the mail.jar and activation.jar into web-inf/lib,my project is run onto the localhost,but after clicking the submit button in my SendMail.jsp page it displays a error like :- "HTTP Status 500 - javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 465;".So what can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a mail server setup on your machine at localhost?  You should use a valid smtp mail server.  If your company has one you could use that or you could try to use google or something...or you could install your own mail server and configure on your machine

Comment: No I didn't setup any smtp server on my machine.I want to send mail from google mail to other account.
Can you tell me how to setup smtp server(gmail) in my machine at localhost?

Comment: Yes,It's run after changing `props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");` to
 `props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");`.

Comment: add java-mail dependency if you are using maven build tool

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException

Add the [mail.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html) for example in your tomcat lib (/catalina_home/commons/libs/) or your web application file (see web-inf/lib).

Also you might need the [activation jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jaf11-139815.html).

For latest javax.mail.jar see https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home

Comment: Now it run on the localhost but when I submit from my SendMail.jsp page it will show an error likes"HTTP Status 500 - javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 465;"

Comment: Yes,It's run after changing `props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");`
to 
`props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");`

Answer (score 3):

You miss `javax.mail-<version>.jar` in your classpath. Download it and add it to your classpath. It is possible that you miss also the dependencies of this jar.